# Unable to open inetcpl.cpl GPO Settings Configured Without Admin

Tags: windows-7, internet, group-policy

I'm having difficulty running `inetcpl.cpl`. My GPO setting: `Run only specified Windows applications` allows Control Panel by including `control.exe`. Keep in mind that I can run control.exe, but not inetcpl.cpl.

The reason why I choose to Whitelist and not Blacklist Apps is because it's easier to maintain. Blacklisting apps means there will always be questionable executables to restrict and this eliminates the idea of "Set & Forget" for a PC to be used as a Kiosk.

## NOT WORKING

- running `rundll32.exe inetcpl.cpl`
- running `control.exe inetcpl.cpl` with GPO setting `Prohibit access to the Control Panel: Not Configured`

## WORKAROUND

- No Suggestions Worked

  - Instead, make account admin and **configure inetcpl.cpl before blacklisting control.exe**
  - the reason why I chose to blacklist is because for some reason inetcpl.cpl configuration won't apply with whitlist method of restricting apps in GPO

Comment: Why do you configure that GP setting?

Comment: I configure to Run only specified Windows applications because of it's whitelisting behavior. Allowing apps this way is easier than having to blacklist apps which I can imagine is, arbitrary. Whitelisting apps means the Administrator already has an idea of what needs to be non-restrictive as opposed to finding a damaging executable in the future to be added after the fact it's already harmed the PC.

Comment: Please add the reason in question not in comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you enter `inetcpl.cpl` into the Run dialog, it will run the following command:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\control.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\inetcpl.cpl"
```

which will then run:

```
"C:\Windows\ystem32\rundll32.exe" Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL "C:\Windows\system32\inetcpl.cpl",
```

Therefore, to open the dialog through the Run dialog you will need to whitelist both `control.exe` and `rundll32.exe`.

If you want to limit access to the Control Panel, you could probably blacklist `control.exe` and write a batch file to run the `rundll32.exe` command when you need it. You could then add the batch file to the `%PATH%` variable to make it easy to run from the Run dialog.